# Get name of file in Jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a jenkinsfile and I need to store part of a file's name in a variable to check if it has a word on it. For example, if the name is: project-x.y.z-TEST.ext I want to know if it ends with the -TEST. From the bash, this return the TEST word (if it is in the name):

```
$(echo ${$(ls - b *.ext | head -1)##*-} | cut -f 1 -d '.')
```

But I can't store it in a variable in my jenkinsfile (or don't know how). Any other way to check this in a jenkinsfile?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: @MattSchuchard could you post an example of a regular expresion in a variable?

Comment: Ok I will just post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to perform a regular expression on a string and store the capture in a variable is:

```
var = string =~ /regex/
```

For example, using your example of a string `project-x.y.z-TEST.ext` where you want to store the capture in a variable, we could do:

```
var = 'project-x.y.z-TEST.ext' =~ /-([A-Z]+)\.ext/
```

This would return `true` for a successful regular expression check, and then capture `TEST`. The string `TEST` would then be assigned to the variable `var`.

If the file name string was assigned to a variable `filename`, we alter this with:

```
var = filename =~ /-([A-Z]+)\.ext/
```

However, since your original problem as stated is to merely check if a file name has a string in it, what you probably really want here is to check the string in the file name and store the boolean result. This is instead of storing that part of the string to perform equality conditional checks against later. In that case, all you really need is:

```
test = filename =~ /-TEST\.ext/
```

and test would store `true` for future conditional usage.

Three important things to note here:

- You need to fine tune the regular expression and its associated capture for your specific use case. Make it greedier or more restrictive based upon your expected matches and checks. I was only working with the one general example given.
- The variables `var` and `test` need to be assigned to `null` immediately after your last usage of it. It is non-serializable, and therefore will cause an error in the Jenkins Pipeline if it persists after its last use. For example:

  ```
  var = filename =~ /-([A-Z]+)\.ext/
  print "Using ${var} for the first time."
  print "Using ${var} for the last time."
  var = null
  ```
- For declarative syntax pipelines, these code examples need to be nested in `script {}` blocks.

Comment: You couldn't have explained yourself better. Thanks!